# Regular expression: <?>?=?\d{4}: what does it match?

Tags: c#, regex

In a C# class, I came across this regular expression:

```
<?>?=?\d{4}
```

It is pretty obvious that its last part (`\d{4}`) matches 4 decimal digits but what about `<?>?=?`? What does it match?

Thanks for any explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four digits at the end preceded by the `<` , `>` and `=` occurring zero or once in that order.

Match:

```
<>=1234
>=1234
=1234
1234
<=1234
```

Comment: @adorablepuppy - I think the OP explained the `\d{4}` so they didn't bother :)

Comment: @Guffa, as I said above, I just think expressing the complete regex was a nicer answer. That said again, your answer was correct too, as was Howard's. I've given a voteup to each of you who had the answer. My comment wasn't intended to offend anyone. It was instead meant to express appreciation to the answerer on a nice answer. I'll remove my original comment.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `'<?>?=?'` matches a '<' char (or none) possibly followed by a '>' possibly followed by a '='. Thus all of the following will match:

1. ''
2. '<'
3. '>'
4. '='
5. '<>'
6. '<='
7. '>='
8. '<>='

Answer (score 2):

The question mark after the characters make it optional, so it matches any combination where each character can be present or not:

- <>=
- <>
- <=
- <
- >=
- >
- =
- 

It's probably meant to match any of the three characters on its own, but then you would rather use `[<>=]?` instead.